# Make ModelForm field's blank attribute dynamic

Tags: django

I have a user model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        unique=True,
    )

    password = models.CharField(
        max_length=160,
        blank=True,
    )
```

I would like the blank attribute to be true only when editing an existing user and false when adding a new user.

I am trying something like:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'password': PasswordInput(),
        }

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Only change password when not blank
        if request.POST['password'] != '':
            obj.password = encrypt(request.POST['password'])
        else:
            if obj.pk is not None:
                obj = obj.__class__._default_manager.get(pk=obj.pk)
            else:
                self.form.Meta.model.password.blank = False
        obj.save()
```

I am getting this error:

```
type object 'User' has no attribute 'password'
```

So this line is not working:

```
self.form.Meta.model.password.blank = False
```

Is it possible to switch the value of blank from true to false and vice versa based on whether adding a new user or editing existing user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it our myself. This works just fine:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'password': PasswordInput(),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()

        if self.instance.pk is None and self.cleaned_data['password'] == '':
            self._update_errors(ValidationError({
                'password': [
                    'Required when creating a new user',
                ]
            }))

        return cleaned_data

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Only change password when not blank
        if request.POST['password'] != '':
            obj.password = encrypt(request.POST['password'])
        elif obj.pk is not None:
            obj = obj.__class__._default_manager.get(pk=obj.pk)
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to implement your requirement.

If the `password` field can contain blank values then you should set `blank=True` in your model and then implement the validation logic in your forms.